# When I use Python to find substring, I can't understand why this happens

Tags: python, string, if-statement

```py
str1 = "E2ab"
str2 = "E2"
if str1.find(str2):
    print("find it")
```

I thought it would print "find it", but in fact, it won't. Why?

The Python version is 3.8.

I make the encoding=utf-8 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: if str1 starts with what you're searching for (str2), the index of str2 in str1 is 0, thus the `if` statement will be evaluated to false, and the if-block not executed.

Comment: And `-1` is [truth-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so it would "find" values of `str2` that actually _weren't_ in `str1`. Use `str2 in str1`.

Comment: As you are not interested in the position of the match, just whether there is a match, do `if str2 in str1:`

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns the index in `str1` where `str2` can be found. In this case, `str2` occurs right at the beginning of `str1`, so `0` is returned. `0` is a false-y, so the `if` condition isn't fulfilled. You can explicitly check that the returned index is non-negative:

```py
if str1.find(str2) >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening beacuse of return value of the find method in Python. The find method returns the lowest index of the substring if it is found in the string. If it is not found, it returns -1.

In your case, str1.find(str2) returns 0 because the substring "E2" starts at index 0 in the string "E2ab". When you use this in an if statement, 0 is considered to be False in a boolean context. Any number other than 0 is considered to be True.

```
str1 = "E2ab"
str2 = "E2"
if str1.find(str2) != -1:
    print("find it")
```

This will print "find it" because you're explicitly checking whether the find method found the substring at an index other than -1.

Answer (score -1):

`String.find()` returns the index of first occurence of the substring, and -1 if no substring is found. In your case, `0` is returned because the substring starts at that index, and the if statement evaluates zero as false. For the sedired behaviour, you can either use `string2 in string1` or `string1.contains(string2)`